# libc: pthread_create failed: couldn't allocate 1040384-byte stack: Out of memory

Tags: android, executorservice, scheduledexecutorservice, event-bus

I Have an `EventBus()` that runs and looping until it goes to my other `Fragment` when my app starts. when I idle the app for at least 30++ minutes,  I'm getting this stacktrace:

```
10-11 10:23:46.315 3790-4797/com.jti.mikee.jti_pos W/libc: pthread_create failed: couldn't allocate 1040384-byte stack: Out of memory
10-11 10:23:46.315 3790-4797/com.jti.mikee.jti_pos E/dalvikvm: pthread_create (stack size 16384 bytes) failed: Try again
```

I also use `ScheduleExecutorService()` on `onCreateView()`

```
scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(4);
```

This is the declaration of my `EventBus()`

```
 public static final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new EB_TapCard());
    }
};
```

and on my `onResume()` this is the code

```
 @Override
public void onResume() {
    Log.e("current_module",current_module);

    super.onResume();
    try {
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
        rfscanner = scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(mRunnable, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and lastly, this is my `onPause()`  method

```
 @Override
public void onPause() {
    try {
        getContext().unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    rfscanner.cancel(true);
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    super.onPause();
}
```

I'm wondering that when I idle my device, The runnable is still running. How can I pause/resume it? much appreciated.

**EDIT**

As of now, I have tried to add a function `Callback()`. It's working well but after I tap the card, The Card Reader is not reading the second card. how can I make it loop without making the memory full??

```
class CallBackThread extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            RFCardInterface.waitForCardPresent(RFCardInterface.CONTACTLESS_CARD_MODE_AUTO, 1, -1);
            if (RFCardInterface.isCallBackCalled &&
                    RFCardInterface.notifyEvent.eventID == RFCardInterface.CONTACTLESS_CARD_EVENT_FOUND_CARD) {

                IDCatcher = StringUtility.ByteArrayToString(RFCardInterface.notifyEvent.eventData,
                        RFCardInterface.notifyEvent.eventData.length);

                IDCatcher = IDCatcher.substring(9, 21).replace(" ", "");
                Log.e("IDCatcher", IDCatcher);


                EventBus.getDefault().post(new EBTest2());
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? Reading at your code, I can't figure out ... you want to constantly broadcast events over EventBus every 2 seconds, once the page is foreground? Or ... ?

Comment: I need to pause the looping code once the device screen is on but standby, and if I want to use it, The looping code will run again

Comment: please answer me: why would you need such looping code in first place? To accomplish what?

Comment: because on my code ATM, even if the device is on standby, the `Runnable()` is still running. That is my point of view why that error occurs

Comment: Because on our POS device, We have a RFID Card Reader that needs to read a specific card to do transactions

Comment: Posting an event over EventBus every 2 seconds, I doubt it will create a OOM exception. My best guess, given the few info you give, is that the executors or the thread pools are constantly created and never gcc'd.

Comment: "We have a RFID Card Reader that needs to read a specific card to do transactions" -> why do you need a 2s ping for doing that? Why can't you read it on-demand, when you need it?

Comment: Try something along these lines: forget pools and executors, just onCreate() instantiate a page's handler _new Handler()_ and post to it with a 2 second delay the runnable that you have. Keep a reference to the runnable. OnPause() remove the (referenced) runnable from the (referenced) handler. Add it onResume(). Is this clear or do you want to see the code? Try it out, I think it will fix your OOM.

Comment: as of now, That is my way to get that card. I don't know yet that kind of process. thank you for your suggestion mate. I think It will help for the crashing part right?

Comment: @Alessio Its clear. but can I have a sample code for references?

Comment: there you go! That's my best guess, given the few details I have, to fix your crash ... to make sure it does, you would either try my suggestion and see that the crash doesn't happen anymore, or debug and find out exactly why the bug happens with your code, so to have full understanding. My gut feeling is that using executors and all that part is the culprit, Android system provides you better mechanisms to accomplish your task

Comment: Ok mate, Ill try this after lunch. Thank you so much for the suggestion and answering this question. God bless you

Comment: you're welcome + let me know if it worked :)

Comment: One more comment: when you register or unregister to / from EventBus, better you guard your code: _if (!EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this)) // then register_ and the other way around for unregistering.

Comment: noted on it. Ill try it later. thank you

Comment: Hi @Alessio, as of now when I Idle the device (but the screen is on) after an hour, the app crashes. how to avoid it?

Comment: Hi Alessio. the error still occurs :(

Comment: I guess it's time to debug and profile ... maybe related to the customized device?

Comment: @Alessio please see my updated answer. Ill put the additional codes

Answer (score 1):

Try something along these lines:

```
private Handler mHandler;                           // the handler to this activity
private Runnable mCallback;        // the callback to 2s loop

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // ...
    mHandler = new Handler();
    mCallback = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new EB_TapCard());
            // schedule next run here
            scheduleNextRun();            
        }
    };
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    scheduleNextRun();
} 

@Override
public void onPause() {
    cleanUpRun();
} 

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // needed in case the system will force-kill your process
    cleanUpRun();
} 

private void cleanUpRun() {
    if (mHandler != null) {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mCallback);
    }
}

private void scheduleNextRun() {
    // clean up beforehand
    cleanUpRun();
    if (mHandler != null) {
        mHandler.postDelayed(mCallback, 2000L);
    }
}
```

idea is that every time you enter the page, you post-delayed your runnable, and you remove it when you go out; once you run it, and it gets the callback executed, you schedule the next run, and so on.

Comment: Hi again @Alessio, As of now I have tried this answer. The card reader is working well. But the log and process is still running even if the device is idle.

Comment: Hi again. after 1 hour letting the device screen is on but standby, I still get error. here is the snippet 
https://pastebin.com/sHnP0Ent

Comment: @MikeGorospe sorry to hear that ... that's very peculiar ... the stacktrace doesn't point anywhere, as I can see ... did you remove / commented out all the unneeded code, especially the one about creating executors and thread pools?

Comment: also this doesn't happen if you don't have your app installed on that device, right? And which device is it, and which Android version is running? Last but not least, what do you exactly mean with "the device screen is on but standby"? I mean, you leave the device on, press the 'home' button so your app goes background (or do you keep it foreground?), and then at one point the screen goes black?

Comment: also, with Studio you can profile your memory, and try to see what's constantly increasing until the OOM

Comment: hmm I'm letting my app run and stand by. this device is a POS so its customized. and running on android kitkat. I can't view the profile memory because the minimum version supported was lollipop